# How do you import font-face rules in React-jss?

Tags: reactjs, jss

I'm using React-JSS. I've been able to use the createUseStyles method to add styles to various elements. Now I want to set up some font-face rules but I'm not sure how I would do that with React-JSS.

In normal html, you'd define the font-face rules in index.css and import the css file in index.js. Then you'd be able to use the font-family name as defined in index.css. But what's the procedure in React-JSS?

Answer (score 1):

I had to figure this out. If someone has something better, please share.

```
import React from 'react'
import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss'


const useStyles = createUseStyles({
    '@font-face': [
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Thin.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 100,
        },
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 200,
        },
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Light.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 300,
        },
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 400,
        },
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 500,
        },
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 600,
        },
        {
            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
            src: 'url(/assets/fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Bold.ttf)',
            fontWeight: 700,
        },
    ],
})

function FontFaces(props) {
    useStyles()
    return props.children
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FontFaces>
               <div>Whatever else</div>
            </FontFaces>
        )
    }
}
```